# Select data from one year before and after

Tags: sql

I am using the following query to pull one year future orders. Is there any way I can pull the data one year before and after today date?

```
SELECT ord_ln.prdnum AS 'Product', ord.cusnam, product.prddsc AS 'Description',
       ord_ln.stdnetwgt AS 'Case_Weight', ord_ln.prdlincod AS 'Line_Code',
       ord_ln.ordqty AS 'Order_Qty', ord.plnshpdat AS 'Plan_Ship_Date'
FROM velocity.dbo.ord ord,
     velocity.dbo.ord_ln ord_ln,
     velocity.dbo.product product
WHERE ord.ordtky = ord_ln.ordtky
  AND product.prdtky = ord_ln.prdtky
  AND ((ord.plnshpdat Between DATEADD(dd,0,GETDATE()) And DATEADD(dd,365,GETDATE())))
ORDER BY ord_ln.prdlincod
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Thanks I will keep in mind :)

Comment: You have both product specific syntax and product specific functions there. Which dbms are you using???

Answer (score 0):

Declare 2 variables and calculate years before using in query.(Just in case you're concerned with performance ;) )

```
Declare @NextYearDate Date= DATEADD(YY,1,getdate())
Declare @PrevYearDate Date= DATEADD(YY,-1,getdate())

SELECT ord_ln.prdnum AS 'Product', ord.cusnam, product.prddsc AS 'Description',
   ord_ln.stdnetwgt AS 'Case_Weight', ord_ln.prdlincod AS 'Line_Code',
   ord_ln.ordqty AS 'Order_Qty', ord.plnshpdat AS 'Plan_Ship_Date'
FROM velocity.dbo.ord ord,
   velocity.dbo.ord_ln ord_ln,
   velocity.dbo.product product
WHERE ord.ordtky = ord_ln.ordtky
   AND product.prdtky = ord_ln.prdtky
   AND (ord.plnshpdat Between @PrevYearDate and @NextYearDate)
ORDER BY ord_ln.prdlincod
```

Comment: Thanks Mahesh Chand, is there any way I can use with the variables, I am using Excel to pull the data from SQL and taking forever.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would write the query:

```
SELECT ol.prdnum as Product, o.cusnam, p.prddsc as Description,
       ol.stdnetwgt as Case_Weight, ol.prdlincod as Line_Code,
       ol.ordqty as Order_Qty, o.plnshpdat as Plan_Ship_Date
FROM velocity.dbo.ord o JOIN
     velocity.dbo.ord_ln ol
     ON o.ordtky = ol.ordtky JOIN
     velocity.dbo.product p
     ON p.prdtky = ol.prdtky
WHERE o.plnshpdat Between DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()) And DATEADD(year, 1, GETDATE())
ORDER BY ol.prdlincod;
```

Changes:

- I simplified the table aliases to be abbreviations of the tables:  easier to write and to read.
- I introduced explicit `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- I removed the single quotes around the column aliases.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  You are likely to make a mistake using them for column names.
- I changed the date arithmetic to be what your question is asking for.

Comment: I was using the GUI to make query, I will keep it mind Thanks Gordon Linoff